# What's the rationale when finding limits that are undefined by direct substitution but defined by approaching?

Tags: calculus, limits

In this video:
[Khan academy video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-limits-new/ab-1-5b/v/undefined-limit-by-substitution?modal=1)

With $f(x)=\frac{x}{ln(x)}$

The limit is said to be undefined when solved by direct substitution for $x=1$. However, isn't the whole point of limits to find what the value would be if the equation didn't evaluate to undefined? The value it's approaching regardless of whether there happens to be a whole at this specific value?
Why would direct substitution be used for the value if the value comes out as undefined in the first place?

Comment: Please don't expect the volunteer helpers on this site to watch an entire video. It's definitely true that $\lim_{x\to1} \frac x{\ln x}$ does not exist, but if you want a specific argument critiqued, you should include the entire argument in the question. (I suspect you're misunderstanding what is said in the video.)

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the feedback. It appears that the equation is unbounded in two separate directions, which gives a result of "Does not exist," so I will rephrase and reorient my question.

Comment: @GregMartin I have reformatted my question so that it is not necessary to watch the video, and made a separate post. Thanks for your feedback. I don't spend enough time on forum sites. See the new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4388047/how-do-we-know-when-direct-substitution-is-the-proper-approach-for-a-limit