# How do we know when direct substitution is the proper approach for a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

In the equation $y=\frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x+2}$, the limit as $\lim_{x→-2}$ is $-4$. However, direct substitution would give a result of "Does not exist".

Given that direct substitution can variously be either appropriate for identifying a limit, or correct in saying that the limit does not exist, or (as in this case) **incorrect** in saying that the limit does not exist, how do we know if direct substitution should be used?

My best guess is that a graphical analysis is the typical first step.

Comment: There are no rules for this. Understanding is your friend. In general, if direct substitution does not lead to an obvious problem then it is (probably) the correct limit. Looking at a graph is a good idea.

Comment: It is also important to bear in mind that the value of a limit is about the values of the point **near and around $-2$** but not **at $-2$** (or whatever the point you're taking the limit to is), and what those values approach as $x$ gets closer and closer to that point. For $x \ne -2$, we see that $y \equiv x-2$, and naturally as $x$ gets closer but still unequal to $-2$, $y$ will get closer and closer to $-4$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Your "in general..." rule of thumb is basically the theorem that elementary functions are continuous where defined.

Comment: @MarkS. Indeed. I thought it best not to be that explicit for this OP for this question.

Comment: I appreciate @MarkS. 's specificity. Thank you all.

Comment: Yes, it's true that the value of a limit depends solely on the behaviour of a function *around*, but not *at*, a certain point. To illustrate this point, consider the function $f$ defined as follows: if $x$ is rational, then $f(x)=1$, and if $x$ is irrational, then $f(x)=0$. If we tried to apply the "direct substitution" method, then we would incorrectly conclude that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)=1 \, .
$$

Comment: However, it sometimes happens that $f$ is both defined at a point $c$, and that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$. When this is the case, we say that $f$ is *continuous* at $c$. It is in this case, and in this case only, that the method of "direct substitution" works.

Comment: Here is the crucial point: it is almost certain that every function that you have been familiarised with at school is continuous at each point in its domain. This is because, in school, it is common to only be exposed to a special class of functions known as the [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). The precise definition of elementary function is perhaps a little technical (but still worth looking at), and varies from author to author.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer this question, it is interesting to remember the definition of limits in $\textbf{R}$.

Consider a real-valued function $f:X\to Y$ with real domain and an accumulation point $a$ from $X$. We say that the limit of $f$ when $x$ approaches $a$ is $L$ iff the following statement is true:
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta_{\varepsilon} > 0)(\forall x\in X)(0 < |x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

As you can see, in order to define the limit of a function at a point, the proposed function need not be defined at this point. But it is required that we can study the behavior of $f$ when $x$ is as close to $a$ as one wants, without assuming the value $a$ itself. This is the case of the proposed limit in the body of the question and, by the above mentioned reason, we can cancel the term $x + 2$.

However, if we also know that $f$ is continuous, then $L = f(a)$. In such case, it is possible to replace the value of $a$ at each entry $x$ of the proposed expression. Here is an example:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to a}(x^{2} + 2x + 1) = a^{2} + 2a + 1
\end{align*}

This basically address the problem from your question (as I have understood).

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: I'm still in High School, so this went a bit over my head, but I enjoy self-studying mathematics. I'm going to guess which subjects I should learn more about to understand the second paragraph and subsequent statement, since I have little understanding of them. Should I be familiar with Discrete Mathematics and Linear Algebra to understand paragraph 2 and the following statement?

Comment: @IsaacPhilo I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_analysis#Limits_and_convergence) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_analysis#Continuity) references should suffice.

Comment: I'm midway through calculus right now, and understanding all of this a little better now. Thanks for the early introduction to epsilon-delta form!